# Optimise filtering function for runtime in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, filter

```
def filter_data(df, raw_col,threshold,filt_col):
    df['pct'] = None
    df[filt_col] = None
    df[filt_col][0] = df[raw_col][0]
    max_val = df[raw_col][0]
    for i in range(1,len(df)):
        df['pct'][i] = (df[raw_col][i] - max_val)*1.0 / max_val
        if abs(df['pct'][i]) < threshold:
            df[filt_col][i] = None
        else:
            df[filt_col][i] = df[raw_col][i]
            max_val = df[raw_col][i]
    df = df.dropna(axis=0, how='any').reset_index()
    return df


from random import randint
some_lst = [randint(50, 100) for i in range(0,50)]
some_df = pd.DataFrame({'raw_col':some_lst})
some_df_filt = filter_data(some_df,'raw_col',0.01,'raw_col_filt')
```

The goal to create a new column(filt_col) where record from numeric column (raw_col) are removed with the following logic; if rate of change between two adjacent rows is less than threshold remove the latter.
It works but is very inefficient in terms of running time.
Any hints on how I could optimise it?

Comment: Could you please share an example of your initial df and the result you're looking for?

Comment: " some_df_filt "  and specifically the column " raw_col_filt " is the desirable output...

Comment: I meant a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If you can produce that it would be easier to help you out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIUC, you can do this very simply using [`.pct_change()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pct_change.html) and `loc`

First

```
df['pctn'] = df.raw_col.pct_change()
```

Then

```
threshold  = 0.01
df.loc[df.pctn.abs() >= threshold]
```

You can check that this solution yields the same result as yours, which you said *works, but is slow*

```
df.loc[df.pctn.abs() >= 0.01].raw_col.tolist() == some_df_filt.raw_col.tolist()
True
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. When testing, the speedup is several orders of magnitude. Where the algorithm in the question operates on a dataframe using lots of code outside of the pandas/numpy api (effectively rendering pandas/numpy useless from an efficiency standpoint), this answer uses the api effectively, keeping things out of the python realm. From a practical perspective, you don't need anything better than this. Where my crappy desktop was taking minutes to do 1000 numbers with the original algorithm, I can now do 10,000,000 with this answer in 1.1 seconds.

Comment: I was trying to avoid using this method and I came up with my function because I would like to have the logic being transferred across different languages effortlessly. But thinking about it, it doesnt make much sense to have a universal mediocre solution instead of using each languages' strengths.